# How do I get/open a CSS file while parsing the HTML of a website?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, html-parsing

I'm trying to open a css file via the html markup of a website, all I want to do is change the hex values of colors.

**Note**: I am doing this from my own website, hence I cannot *just change the values*.

I am using the ASP.NET MVC 4.5 Framework.

Comment: You're working on your own website, but you cannot change the values? What sort of limitations are you struggling with here?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this to your html page:

```
<link href="Your-file-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the question again, are you trying to temporarily change the value on any given website directly in the browser?

If that is the case, you can use the inspect tool (F12 in Chrome), more details here; https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles